# COUNT function in SQL - ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

First of all here are the concerned tables :

[image]

I want to display the following details in a table :

```
CategoryName | DateCreated | DateUpdate | No. of Products
```

Now , the fourth column which is **`No. of Products`** is my problem. As you can see in the DB image :

**`CategoryID`** is a foreign-key in the **`tblProduct`**

So this(**`No. of Products`**) column should contain a total no. of products belonging to a particular category.

I am confused in how to get this **`COUNT`**.

Here is what I tried :

```
select tblCategory.*,
       COUNT(tblProduct.CategoryID) AS 'Cat_Count'
from tblCategory

inner join tblProduct on tblCategory.CategoryID = tblProduct.CategoryID;
```

I got the following error :

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tblCategory.CategoryID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: `CategoryID` is also foreign key in `tblProduct`

Comment: @Shaharyar : Oh yes I completely oversaw that detail >_< .. Stil any query for the count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a simple join with a group by clause. You just have to group the `CategoryID`:

```
SELECT cat.CategoryName, cat.DateCreated, cat.DateUpdate, COUNT(pro.ProductID) [No. of Products]
FROM tblCategory cat JOIN tblProduct pro
ON cat.CategoryID = pro.CategoryID
Group By cat.CategoryID, cat.CategoryName, cat.DateCreated, cat.DateUpdate
```

Comment: Thank you! It was stupid of me to ask such a question. But I learnt some new thing like - `COUNT(pro.ProductID) [No. of Products]`... i dint know that ... And i do not understand the GROUP BY clause -_-

Comment: why do we need to include all the selected columns in group by columns ?

Comment: Its hard to explain it in a sentence. Please refer to this article and your concepts will be clear about GROUP BY clause: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.CategoryName 
     , C.DateCreated 
     , C.DateUpdate 
     , COUNT(*)  [No. of Products]
FROM tblCategory c
INNER JOIN tblProduct P ON c.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
GROUP BY C.CategoryName , C.DateCreated , C.DateUpdate
```